# I can't get the included variables. Why?

Tags: javascript, php, html, variables

I want to create a POP-UP Window if I click on a picture. And the Pop up is just a div-box which "opens" with javascript. I would've nine boxes. So I thougt I could minimalize the code and just use one div-box and get the values out of a database.
I have two files. First of all is the index.php. The following code is just a part of the hole file.

```
            <div id="modal_box" style="display: none;">
                <div id="modal_1" style="display: none;">
                  <span onClick="closeModal('modal_1')" class="close" id="close">&times;</span>
                    <text id="header_modal"><?php echo $ext_modalHeader; ?></text><br />
                    <text id="p_modal"><?php echo $ext_modalHUnderline; ?> <a href="<?php echo $ext_modalVerlinkung; ?>" target="_blank"><u><?php echo $ext_modalModel; ?></u></a></text>
                    <br /><br /><hr /><br /><br />
                  <div class="modal_content">
                    <table id="com">
                      <tr>
                        <td id="l">
                          <?php $modal_1_i = 0;

                          include("src/includes/evaluation.php");

                          $modal_1_state = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM pictureManager WHERE pictureSession = :psession AND picturePlacement = 0");
                          $modal_1_state->execute(array("psession" => $ext_pictureSession));
                          while($modal_1 = $modal_1_state->fetch()) {
                            $modal_1_i++;

                            if($modal_1_i == 1) {
                              $startPicture = $modal_1['pictureSRC'];
                            }
                            ?>
                               <img onClick="bigit('modalpic_<?php echo $modal_1_i; ?>')" id="modalpic_<?php echo $modal_1_i; ?>" src="<?php echo $modal_1['pictureSRC']; ?>" style="width: 20%;" />
                            <?php
                          } ?>
                          <br /><br />
                          <div id="det">
                            <h2><?php echo $ext_gearHeader; ?></h2>
                            <p><?php echo $ext_gearDesc; ?></p>
                          </div>
                        </td>
                        <td id="r">
                            <img id="bigPicture" src="<?php echo $startPicture; ?>" style="width:80%; padding: 0;margin: 0;" />
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
```

And that is the evaluation.php file, which is included in the index.php

```
<?php
  session_start();

  $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=databaseexample', 'xyz', '123');

  if(isset($_POST['id']) && !empty($_POST['id'])) {

    $evaluation_modid = $_POST['id'];

    $evaluation_mod_state = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM mM WHERE pictureSession = :psession");
    $evaluation_mod_state->execute(array("psession" => $evaluation_modid));
    $evaluation_modRes = $evaluation_mod_state->fetch();

    if($evaluation_mod_state) {
      $ext_pictureSession = $evaluation_modRes['pictureSession'];
      $ext_modalHeader = $evaluation_modRes['modalHeader'];
      $ext_modalHUnderline = $evaluation_modRes['modalHUnderline'];
      $ext_modalVerlinkung = $evaluation_modRes['modalVerlinkung'];
      $ext_modalModel = $evaluation_modRes['modelName'];
      $ext_gearHeader = $evaluation_modRes['gearHeader'];
      $ext_gearDesc = $evaluation_modRes['gearBeschreibung'];
    } else {
      printf("err");
    }
  }

 ?>
```

If I print the $ext_... - variables in the evaluation.php I get the correct result. But I don't get the right result if I print them in the index.php. Why?

Comment: Is `$_POST['id']` set? You use `echo $ext_modalHeader;` and others before you include the file. What is `<text ...` supposed to do?

Comment: @brombeer ```$_POST['id']``` is set. Yeah I know. This would not work. But everything under the include section should work (?). ```<text>...``` does work. Its just a personalized tag.

Answer (score 1):

> If I print the $ext_... - variables in the evaluation.php I get the correct result. But I don't get the right result if I print them in the index.php. Why?

It looks like you don't send the POST request and `src/includes/evaluation.php` doesn't set the variables because of `if(isset($_POST['id']) && !empty($_POST['id'])) {` condition.

Or `$evaluation_mod_state` value is `false`.

Comment: I can print the $_POST['id'] variable in the Console. That works 100%.

Comment: @Levi great, can you check the `$evaluation_mod_state` value?

Comment: Yeah. Is set true.

Comment: @Levi did you print the $ext_... - variables in the index.php after `include` statement?

I created a small test case, you can execute it in the console:
`echo '<?php if (true) { $foo = "hi"; }' > test_include.php`
then run `php -a` and enter `include 'test_include.php'; echo $foo;` in the php interactive shell. You should get `hi` text message

Comment: Yeah. I can echo the variables if I give them a value manually. After the ```if($evaluation_mod_state)``` query, I took the $ext_gearDesc variable and gave them a example value like "test". I could print/echo that in the index.php without any problems... It does not make sense. I don't understand this.

Comment: @Levi that means SQL query returns NULL value for the gearBeschreibung column, you can use `var_dump($evaluation_modRes['gearBeschreibung']);` to check this.